# iOS UIScrollView's width is different from the width set in constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm new to `iOS` auto layout. I want to implement a view pager using `UIScrollView` with paging enabled. I set the scrollView to (w, h) to (200, 65), but the width of scrollView is always 240 at runtime. As the result, the offset of contents, the label I added into the scrollView, do not match to the scrollView's width. Why are they different? How do I get the right width?

[image]
[image]

```
private let contents = ["This is the 1st message",
                        "This is the 2nd message",
                        "This is the 3rd message"]

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("scrollView.bounds = \(scrollView.bounds)")
    print("scrollView.frame = \(scrollView.frame)")

    var x: CGFloat = 0
    for content in contents {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(x, 0, 0, 0))
        label.text = content
        label.sizeToFit()
        print("label.frame = \(label.frame)")
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
        x += scrollView.bounds.width
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.bounds.height)
}

Output:
scrollView.bounds = (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)
scrollView.frame = (80.0, 156.0, 240.0, 128.0)
label.frame = (0.0, 0.0, 178.0, 20.3333333333333)
label.frame = (240.0, 0.0, 185.666666666667, 20.3333333333333)
label.frame = (480.0, 0.0, 182.333333333333, 20.3333333333333)
```

Comment: add scrollview constraint x and y position.

Comment: What is your current size class?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa my current size class is wCompact hRegular

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya I added the following for x and y position,
(Scroll View.leading = leading + 80) and
(Scroll View.top = top + 90), but it still doesn't work

Comment: @WayneHuang is the size class wanted? are you using different size classes?

Comment: you are add programmatically or ui. your screen shot doesn't display for ui

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa Yes, I want my app only for iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are using a size class `wCompact hRegular` for this constraints, so if you have another size class (for example different orientations) you don't have these constraints available.

To set the constraints just for `iPhone` I suggest doing it programmatically:

```
if (IDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {
    // Set constraints or a different UIVIew here 
}
```

And if you have your app available for iPhone Only you can use the class size `Any-Any` avoiding the programmatically set.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. After I set the size class to wAny hAny, it works as a charm!